# Why is my THREE.js Documentation Box isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, three.js

I'm a Beginner who tries to learn **THREE.js** I went through the **THREE.js** Documentation and tried to code that but when I run my HTML page it was empty and I have no clue what to do and I used visual studio code to do coding

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Our Javascript will go here.
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
      );

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
      const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(cube);

      camera.position.z = 5;

      const animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, the only change I made is to insert the library via [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

You have the "three.js" script locally so make sure you have that file in the js folder and that the folder is in the root of your site.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js" integrity="sha512-dLxUelApnYxpLt6K2iomGngnHO83iUvZytA3YjDUCjT0HDOHKXnVYdf3hU4JjM8uEhxf9nD1/ey98U3t2vZ0qQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
      // Our Javascript will go here.
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
      );

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
      const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(cube);

      camera.position.z = 5;

      const animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i used inline script so that is it work or I didn't understand what you have mentioned

Comment: can you please explain it thoroughly

Comment: My code is identical to yours, except for this line: `<script src="js/three.js"></script>`. I load the library from an external site, and it works. So I suppose your problem is due to the loading of the three.js file. Try pressing F12 (on chrome), the developer console, you will probably see a "file not found" error.